# How to use reflection to extract all properties of a certain type?

Tags: java, reflection

I have a number of classes which can include one or more properties of the type `TranslatableText`. Also, some classes may have properties which themselves include such properties such as `List<TranslatableText>` or `Map<String, TranslatableText>`.

How would you go about scanning these classes in an efficient way, also picking up instances of `TranslatableText` in generic collections?

```
class Project{
    String id;
    TranslatableText name;
    List<Action> actions;
}

class Action {
    String id;
    TranslatableText name;
    TranslatableText description;
}

// getter & setters omitted
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a loop like this

```
// for super classes, use recursion.
for(Field f : obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
    Class type = f.getType();
    if (type == String.class || type == TranslatableText.class) {
        Object value = f.get(object);
        if (value != null)
            map.put(f.getName(), value.toString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Peter Lawrey for the initial idea. This is what worked (so far) for me. I had to avoid circular recursion which is why I added the `visited` list. `Arrays`, `Collections` and `Maps` are scanned which is good enough for me at the moment.

```
/**
 * Examine class members for TranslatableTexts. Traverse down into
 * properties including Collections and Maps but ignoring java.lang classes
 * 
 * @param obj
 * @return
 */
public static Collection<? extends TranslatableText> getTranslatables(
        Object obj, List<Object> visited)
{
    List<TranslatableText> result = new ArrayList<TranslatableText>();

    if (obj instanceof TranslatableText)
    {
        result.add((TranslatableText) obj);
        return result;
    }

    if(visited.contains(obj))
        return result;

    visited.add(obj);

    for (Field f : obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields())
    {
        f.setAccessible(true);

        Class type = f.getType();
        if (type.isPrimitive() == false
                && (type.getPackage() == null || type.getPackage()
                        .getName().startsWith("java.lang") == false))
        {
            try
            {
                Object value = f.get(obj);
                if (value != null)
                {
                    if (type.isArray())
                    {
                        Class arraytype = type.getComponentType();
                        if (arraytype == TranslatableText.class)
                        {
                            TranslatableText[] tt = (TranslatableText[]) value;
                            if (tt != null)
                            {
                                for (TranslatableText t : tt)
                                {
                                    result.add(t);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else if (type == TranslatableText.class)
                    {
                        TranslatableText tt = (TranslatableText) value;
                        if (tt != null)
                            result.add(tt);
                    }
                    else if (value instanceof Collection)
                    {
                        for (Object o : (Collection<?>) value)
                        {
                            result.addAll(getTranslatables(o, visited));
                        }
                    }
                    else if (value instanceof Map)
                    {
                        for (Object o : ((Map) value).values())
                        {
                            result.addAll(getTranslatables(o, visited));
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result.addAll(getTranslatables(value, visited));
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```